# Excessive Metadata when getting all states in Test Corda vault

Tags: spring, corda

Im testing a Corda 4 Cordapp and set up a spring web server to make api calls to my cordapps. I have one api called named ```get-all-contract1-states`` which does exactly what it says. It gets all of my contract1 states in the vault.

When I call this function, it does return the states, but also returns an excessive amount of repetitive metadata making the output for 1 state more than 600k lines long.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get-contract1-states", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
fun getContract1s()  = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy(criteria = VaultQueryCriteria(status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL), paging = PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, 200), sorting = Sort(emptySet()), contractStateType = contract1State::class.java).states
```

Most of the repetitive metadata (which makes up about 85% of the 600k lines) is at the end of the Json regarding `"zero":false,"one":false,"fieldSize":256,"fieldName":"SecP256R1Field"`. Are there any flags, options, or simply any way to get back a clean version of the contract without so much excess data. I only care about the variables from the contract, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you currently have will return you a collection of:

```
data class Page<out T : ContractState>(val states: List<StateAndRef<T>>,
                                           val statesMetadata: List<StateMetadata>,
                                           val totalStatesAvailable: Long,
                                           val stateTypes: StateStatus,
                                           val otherResults: List<Any>)
```

Hence why you're getting all the metadata. What you're after in this data object is states (which actually returns StateAndRef) and then just state within each.

The following code should get you what you're after:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get-contract1-states", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        fun getContract1s()  = proxy.vaultQueryBy(criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(status =
        Vault.StateStatus.ALL), paging = PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, 200),
                sorting = Sort(emptySet()), contractStateType = IOUState::class.java).states.map { it.state.data }
```

Note: the key bit here is the mapping to *state.data*